# Kotlin. Java, and PHP performance with MySQL

Tags: java, php, mysql

I have been running some tests on MySQL execution performance for various languages in order to gauge their overall execution time and the results to me seems completely off.

The main goal of the tests were to see how many seconds it takes to pull a list of data from a database table, dump that data into an array of objects, and then output that data onto the screen. Based on the numbers I get, my only assumption is that I must be doing something completely wrong in Java and Kotlin otherwise based on the results, they perform substantially slower. This though makes no sense as they are both compiled languages so their performances should easily compare if not beat the performance from PHP.

Now I am assuming there is something with my code below which is causing the execution time to be considerably slower than PHP and was curious if anyone had any input as to what might be going on, or is the Java mysql connector just a lot slower than the PDO connector in PHP?

> PHP: 0.21993803977966
>
> Kotlin: 0.783954305
>
> Java: 0.716218516

Java Code

```
        Long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3321/database?user=root&password=pass");

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        ArrayList<Entity> contacts = new ArrayList<Entity>();

        ResultSet  rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM contacts" );

        while( rs.next() ){
            contacts.add( new Entity( rs.getString("firstname"), rs.getString("lastname") ) );
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
            contacts.forEach( contact -> stringBuilder.append("huzzah ").append(contact.getFirstName()).append(" ").append(contact.getLastName()).append("\n\r"));
        }

        Long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.print( stringBuilder.toString() );

        Long elapsedTime = ( endTime - startTime );

        double seconds = (double) elapsedTime / 1_000_000_000.0;
        System.out.println( "Total Execution Time: " + seconds );
```

PHP Code

```
<?php

$starttime = microtime(true);

include_once "entity.php";

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3321;dbname=database', "root", "pass");
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM contacts");
$query->execute();

/** @var Entity[] $entities */
$entities = [];

while( $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $entities[] = new Entity( $row['firstname'], $row['lastname']);
}

$buffer = "";

for( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ ){
    foreach ($entities as $entity) {
        $buffer .= "huzzah {$entity->getFirstName()} {$entity->getLastName()}\n\r";
    }
}

echo $buffer;

$endtime = microtime(true);

echo "Script Time: " . ( $endtime - $starttime );
```

Comment: Post the PHP equivalent code so we can see that you're comparing apples to apples. My guess is that the PHP code does not include time to setup the connection to the DB.

Comment: Also note that Java uses just-in-time compilation which might not kick in here. To conduct more reliable benchmarks you should use [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)

Comment: @NotaJD thanks, Just added the PHP code example...

Comment: @Kabe Worth noting that you are doing an incorrect calculation: you do `elapsedTime / 1_000_000_000.0`, with `elapsedTime` being measured in nanos, but you do `( ( $endtime - $starttime ) / 1000)` when using microseconds. It should be `( ( $endtime - $starttime ) / 1000000)`. `1 ns = 1e-9 s`, `1 μs = 1e-6 s`.

Comment: Also try timing *after* the connection is made. This is typically a one-time (or few-time) concern, since bringing up DB connections is not cheap.

Comment: @BackSlash ah whoops, that makes it a bit better. microtime is calculating in seconds so in theory I don't need the / 1000 at all. That made the time now much more accurate by having it at 0.2 seconds. to 0.7 seconds for java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Thomas and @NotaJD for providing the answers. Connecting in Java is considerably slower than PHP, so I specified the start time's after the database connections. However that was not the entire story. The compiler was also not optimised the code as was suggested by @Thomas. I created an export JAR of the project and made a few modifications. The new times were much more reasonable reducing Java's execution time to 0.228579051

```
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3321/database?user=root&password=password");

        Long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        ResultSet  rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM contacts" );

        ArrayList<Entity> contacts = new ArrayList<Entity>(rs.getRow());

        while( rs.next() ){
            contacts.add( new Entity( rs.getString("firstname"), rs.getString("lastname") ) );
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
            contacts.forEach( contact -> stringBuilder.append("huzzah ").append(contact.getFirstName()).append(" ").append(contact.getLastName()).append("\n\r"));
        }

        Long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.print( stringBuilder.toString() );

        Long elapsedTime = ( endTime - startTime );

        double seconds = (double) elapsedTime / 1_000_000_000.0;
        System.out.println( "Total Execution Time: " + seconds );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
 ResultSet  rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM contacts" );
 ArrayList<Entity> contacts = new ArrayList<Entity>(rs.getRow());

    while( rs.next() ){
        contacts.add( new Entity( rs.getString("firstname"), rs.getString("lastname") ) );
    }
```

This will allocate all the storage you need in one call instead of incrementally adding storage for each row.

Never underestimate the performance and capabilities of php. There is a reason half the WEB was developed using php.

Comment: Thanks, that did shave a few milliseconds off the query.